# My Kendo Datepicker is not visible when close to the bottom of the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

When using the Kendo date picker under ASP Razor, the control opens outside the visible area if the picker is close to the bottom of the page. It also opens at quite a distance from the control.

```
@model [Company].DebugViewModel

<h2>Development Debug Page</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Debug", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="DebugDate">Blank Space:</label>
    <div style="height:2000px; background-color:lightgray;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="DebugDate">Debug Date:</label>
    @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(a => a.DebugDate)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:120px;" value="Save" />
</div>
}
```

Here is an image:[image]

Comment: Kendo does not play nice with bootstrap out of the box. Try disabling bootstrap and then see if kendo behaves like it should.

Comment: Try wrapping your markup in a div with border-box: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nest-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, thanks to the feedback I got, I decided to drop bootstrap from the project. Lucky for me this is a desktop only application.

Here is what I ended up using:

```
<style>
body {
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative; /* Fixed Kendo widget box problem */
}
.form-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin: 16px auto;
}
</style>

<div class="k-content form-container">
<ul>
        <li>
            <label for="ID">ID:</label>
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(a => a.ID)
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="Date">Date:</label>
            @Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(a => a.Date)
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```